# consuming a soap webservice-getting 500

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I have a 500 error when trying to consume a soap WS .
code below :
main function :

```
public void Main()
    {
        var action = "XXXXXX";
        string result = SendSOAPRequest("http://XXXXXXXX:80/XXXX",  action, new Dictionary<string, string>() , false);
    }
```

sendrequest method :

```
public void Main()
    {
        var action = "XXXXXX";
        string result = SendSOAPRequest("http://XXXXXXXX:80/XXXX",  action, new Dictionary<string, string>() , false);
    }

    public static string SendSOAPRequest(string url, string action,Dictionary<string, string> parameters, bool useSOAP12 = false)
    {
        try{
        
        XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = new XmlDocument();
        var xmlStr = (useSOAP12)
            ? @"XXXXXX";
        string parms = string.Join(string.Empty, parameters.Select(kv => String.Format("<{0}>{1}</{0}>", kv.Key, kv.Value)).ToArray());
        var s = String.Format(xmlStr, action, new Uri(url).GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + "/", parms);
        soapEnvelopeXml.LoadXml(s);
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url + "/" + action));
        webRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", url);
        webRequest.Headers.Add("XXXXXX", "AG6YUTGV6");
        webRequest.ContentType = (useSOAP12) ? "application/soap+xml;charset=\"utf-8\"" : "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
        webRequest.Accept = (useSOAP12) ? "application/soap+xml" : "text/xml";
        webRequest.Method = "GET";

       string usernamePassword = "username" + ":" + "pass";
        usernamePassword = Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(usernamePassword)); 
        CredentialCache mycache = new CredentialCache();
        webRequest.Credentials = mycache;
        webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + usernamePassword);

        
        using (WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(stream);
               
            }
        }
        
        using (Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
        }

        string result;
        using (WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse())
        {
            using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                result = rd.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            string message = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: Every server is different.  The server doesn't like a parameter in the request.  You have to read the requirements of the server to fix issue or debug the server code.

Comment: jdweng do i need to check with the IT teams for requirements of the server?

Comment: Only the people who wrote the server software would know.